# how to pop a drawing uiview as a model view only half of the screen

Tags: objective-c, ios

I create new viewcontroller class with xib then created uiview inherited class and in xib file custom class I wrote the uiview inherited class name(PaintView).

I am trying to implement a simple drawing feature in my app, I created a simple drawing code which paints on uiview using touchbegain, thouchmoves, drawrect methods in PaintView class.

Till here its all working fine now I want to pop a model of this view, but I want it to display half of the screen, I resize it in interface builder but it is still showing on full screen.

Other posts says create a transparent view add contents at bottom half thats how you will get half model view, but this is not a solution for my problem.

How to properly pop model view but only half of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, don't present it modally.

```
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myXib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[controller.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 320)];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [controller.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -320)];
}];
```

To change the color's I recommend you store the integer values of your color's hues into an array, that way you can stably assign the hue from the integer value of some object in the array:

```
arrayOfColors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0.0", @"0.1", @"0.2", @"0.3", @"0.4", @"0.5", @"0.6", @"0.7", @"0.8", @"0.9", nil];



[[UIColor colorWithHue:[[arrayOfColors objectAtIndex:someIndex]floatValue] saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0]setStroke];
```

Comment: can you also help me in one more thing? I am using [[UIColor blueColor]setStroke]; but now I want to change the color, i created new button and trying to set different color but no luck.

Comment: now on button click i want to change from blue to red or black or green any color. I have created four buttons red, green, blue, black on click of a button i want to change the color

Comment: - (IBAction)red:(id)sender
{
    pickedColor = 0;
}

Comment: but as i choose the new color the already drawn lines color also changed

Comment: how can i choose different colors for drawing?

Comment: @SweetJenny Take a look at the edit to my post and let me know if it helps!